# "Bad Request" error for chromeosdevices.list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I am trying to figure out how to get device information about Chromebooks that my organization uses (using Google Apps Scripts.) Being new to this, I basically tried to modify a tutorial code that would get users from the organization. When I execute the code for users, it works fine, but gives me a "Bad Request (line 7, file "Code") error when I try to run it as below:

```
function getDevices() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    customerId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: 'serialNumber'    
  };
  var response = AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list(optionalArgs);
  var devices = response.devices;
  if (devices && devices.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('Devices:');
    for (i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
      var device = devices[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', device.serialNumber, device.lastSync);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No devices found.');
  }
}
```

I know it's referencing this line for the error:

```
var response = AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list(optionalArgs);
```

I checked with [Google's Directory API documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices/list) to make sure I was passing parameters correctly, but I don't see that being an issue. I have enabled the API under Advanced Google Services, and enabled it on the Cloud Platform API Dashboard (the dashboard shows the requests and errors of my attempts.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I tinkered around with the script and tried entering the customerID directly to the parameters instead of passing it with the other arguments, and I no longer receive the error:

```
function getDevices() {
  var optionalArgs = {   
    maxResults: 200,
    orderBy: 'serialNumber'
  };
  var response = (AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list("my_customer", optionalArgs));
```

I realize the that **my_customer** parameter is optional with the *Users.list* request, it is required with *Chromeosdevices.list*. I am not sure why it does not like having that argument passed, it seems to have been the root of my problem. While it didn't list any devices for me in the log, it did post "No devices found", which means the everything else executed.

Comment: I also figured out the issue as to why I was not getting any devices back. I had to change the line `var devices = response.devices;` to `var devices = response.chromeosdevices;` as _chromeosdevices_ is in the response, as opposed to just _devices_. Yay for learning!